# Spring Boot is ignoring logging levels from external application.properties

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, spring-boot

I am running Spring Boot (version 1.5.2.RELEASE) application packaged in war file on Tomcat. Inside my context file (`conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`) I have specified the path to the external properties file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Environment name="spring.config.location" value="file:/opt/shared/home/.airlines-data/" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Inside the path `/opt/shared/home/.airlines-data/` i have an `application.properties` file with fallowing lines:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
logging.file=/opt/shared/home/.airlines-data/Errors.log
```

The file is read correctly. The property `logging.file=/opt/shared/home/.airlines-data/Errors.log` is also loaded properly and if i change its value to something else the everything works as expected. Unfortunately Spring Boot is ignoring all of the logging level settings. It logs everything from INFO level and above. Also Hibernate logs all of it's queries to the log file. This makes log files very large in short time. Is there any other way to change logging level to WARN or ERROR and disable Hibernate SQL logging using external config? I am using standard logging settings provided by Spring Boot. Below are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-messaging")
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
    compile('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2')
    compile('com.samaxes.filter:cachefilter:2.3.1')
    compile('com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:0.2.12')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.2')
    compile('org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2')
    compile('xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4:2.6.4')
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.jodd:jodd-mail:3.7.1')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

My Error.log file fills really quickly and contains a lot of lines similar to those:

```
2017-02-17 18:45:13.338 DEBUG 5168 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class pl.eb2b.AirlinesApplication,class org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter
2017-02-17 18:45:13.851 DEBUG 5168 --- [localhost-startStop-1]
2017-02-17 18:45:13.851 DEBUG 5168 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/opt/shared/home/.airlines-data/application.properties'
2017-02-17 18:45:13.852 DEBUG 5168 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'classpath:/application.properties'
2017-02-18 00:21:34.997 DEBUG 9026 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@14ab2c1f
2017-02-18 00:21:35.000 DEBUG 9026 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@14ab2c1f
2017-02-20 13:15:09.526 DEBUG 11701 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(*) as y0_ from cars_car_contract this_
```

I have also tried placing logback-spring.xml file inside my class path:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

It worked on my local machine but was ignored on the server.

*Update 2017-04-07:*

I have found some additional information in catalina.out log that contains everything that was printed to the console (maybe it will be helpful):

```
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/repo/versions/8.5.3
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/repo/versions/8.5.3
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3/conf/logging.properties
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DReceiverIp=
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DMagicPort=
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djvm=jelastic
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DjvmRid=
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms32M
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmn30M
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx512M
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xminf0.1
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmaxf0.3
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseG1GC
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseCompressedOops
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3
07-Apr-2017 06:12:48.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3/temp
```

Since my server is a Jelastic based cloud server it was configured automatically with those parameters. Don't know if it has something to do, but param `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3/conf/logging.properties` looks like it has something to do with logging. Below is the content of this file:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = WARNING
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

Comment: Which logger are you using? And what makes you think it is ignoring all the levels? Please provide the configuration of whichever logger you are using like log4j,slf4j etc.

Comment: I am using default Spring Boot configuration so the logger should be the Logback. I don't use any logger config other than those lines from application.properties. I have updated question with few example lines from the log file. Logs from today has already 1,5MB in size and all of the entries are from DEBUG level. Also when i try using this configuration on my local machine (Spring Boot running as a jar file with embed Tomcat) it works as expected and hides all of those log messages. This problem only occurs on a production server when Spring Boot is running as a war file inside Tomcat.

Comment: The output that you have specified shows that a custom pattern has been used. So check your production server's context path and search the resource paths. There must be some logback xml/groovy file or log4j properties/xml file. Or worst Case scenario a configuration class for any of these is setting the log level based on server environment or profile management.

Comment: And even if that doesn't solve it try upgrading your springboot version and check for the results.. I remember having read about a few log related issues in 1.3x

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a logback or log4j config file. I've also updated Spring Boot to the latest 1.5.2.RELEASE. It didn't helped either.

Comment: Are you passing in any command line arguments? Or maybe you have different properties set in your server environment. Check your server's environment variables. You might also want to look for profile specific property files.

Comment: I've updated question with additional data i've found printed to the console during server startup. I think there are all command line arguments passed to Java. The file `/opt/repo/versions/8.5.3/conf/logging.properties` looks like it could have something to do with logging issue but it dosen't contains any Spring or Hibernate related instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some articles ([1](http://javabeat.net/spring-boot-logging/), [2](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)) we were able to find say the following:

> Default Logging Support in Spring Boot
>
> Spring Boot reference document says:
>
> By default, If you use the ‘Starter POMs’, Logback will be used for
>   logging. Appropriate Logback routing is also included to ensure that
>   dependent libraries that use Java Util Logging, Commons Logging, Log4J
>   or SLF4J will all work correctly.

Thus, you can adjust logging level for SpringBoot in application.properties file, most possible by this path:

```
cat /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
logging.level.*=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.boot=OFF
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=OFF
```

After the changes are done, DEBUG messages should disappear from catalina.out